# Value of Summation of $\log(n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, logarithms, summation

**Context:**
I am learning Dijstra's Algorithm to find shortest path to any node, given the start node. Here, we can use Fibonnacci Heap as Priority Queue. Following is few lines of algorithm:

```
For each vertex in PriorityQueue{
    do_something()
}
```

If $V$ is the number of vertices, the subsequent lookup times in the priority queue will be:
$$O(\log V), O(\log V-1), \ldots$$

**Question:**

What would the value of $O(\log V) + O(\log V-1) + O(\log V-2) + .. + O(\log 1)$?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want to find the sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N{\log{n}} = \log \prod_{n=1}^N {n} = \log(N!)$$
Now, using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation):
$$\log N! \sim N\log N$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\log V+\log(V-1)+\log(V-2)+\cdots+\log2+\log1=\log(V!)\sim V\log V$$
The asymptotic $O(V\log V)$ is easy: either one remembers Stirling formula, or one note that the sum on the left is $\leqslant V\log V$ and, keeping only $\frac12V$ terms, $\geqslant\frac12V\log\left(\frac12V\right)\sim\frac12V\log V$.