# What is the order of the sum of log x?

Tags: asymptotics

Let

$$f(n)=\sum_{x=1}^n\log(x)$$

What is $O(f(n))$?

I know how to deal with sums of powers of $x$. But how to solve for a sum of logs?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521421/solve-lnn-thetan-lnn-without-stirling-approximation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of Summation of log(n)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/228744/258990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stirling's formula we have, for $n$ sufficiently large
$$
f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k=\log(n!)\simeq\log(\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n}n^{n+1/2}).
$$
Hence
$$
O(f(n))=\log(\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-n}n^{n+1/2}).
$$

Answer (score 7):

As noted, $f(n)=\log(n!)$.

Trivially, we have
$$
n!\le n^n
$$

Also, using a multiplicative variant of [Gauss's trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Mythology), we have:
$$
(n!)^2 = (1 \cdot n) (2 \cdot (n-1)) (3 \cdot (n-2)) \cdots
                ((n-2) \cdot 3) ((n-1) \cdot 2) (n \cdot 1)
                \ge n^n
$$

This implies that
$$
\frac12 n \log n \le \log(n!) \le n \log n
$$
and so
$$
\log(n!) = \Theta(n\log n)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that the sum starts at $2$. You use the comparison with the integral:
$$
\int_1^n\log x\,dx\leq\sum_{x=2}^n\log x\leq\int_2^{n+1}\log x\,dx.
$$
From there you can see that $O(f(n))=n\log n$.