# Is $f(n) = 2^{\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n)} / n!$ polynomially bounded?

Tags: analysis

The numerator counts the number of different adjacency matrices. I think Sterlings approximation helps to anwser my question but I fail to derive the answer. 
So, is there a polynomial function $g(x)$ such that 
$$f(x) \leq g(x)$$

Comment: Apply $\log$ and use that $\log (n!)\ge \frac12 n \log n$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/543644/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not polynomially bounded. For $n \geqslant 3$, we have $\frac12(n^2-n) \geqslant \frac13 n^2$, so

$$\frac{2^{\frac12(n^2-n)}}{n!} > \frac{2^{\frac13 n^2}}{n^n} = \left(\frac{2^{n/3}}{n}\right)^n.$$

$2^{n/3}$ has exponential growth, so altogether we have superexponential growth.

Comment: Just play with Stirling's approximation on n! and use log's